# eval vs Function() return semantics

Tags: javascript, actionscript, eval, semantics

We have the product (normal desktop app) that wants to pull some data from the Adobe products (from the documents, opened in these products). Since the Apple events are too slow, we implemented a custom interop that sends generated jsx (Adobe's ActionScript3 based on the not long-dead JavaScript 1.5) to Adobe product processes via socket. This is 2000+ times faster than using events, but forces us to do some tricks involving `eval`, with the current goal is to minimise the risks of inadvertently corrupting the state of the JSX engine by the non-isolated `eval`.

This code runs in a trusted environment (not the browser), and the code itself is also trusted, so any security considerations about `eval` are not applicable. The main goal of the question is to prevent the pollution of the global scope performed by the `eval`.

When using the `eval`, then the result of the last expression is considered as the return value of the whole `eval`, e.g. result of the `eval`-ing of the following code will be the value of the `y+2=12` expression.

```js
var res = eval("
    var x = 5;
    var y = x*2;
    y+2;
"); //res = 12
```

At the same time, if we will wrap such a code into the `Function` constructor, then the result will be `undefined`

```js
var res = (new Function("
    var x = 5;
    var y = x*2;
    y+2;
")).call(); //res=undefined
```

To fix the last snippet, we need to add explicit return to the last expression:

```js
var res = (new Function("
    var x = 5;
    var y = x*2;
    return y+2;    // <------- changes here
")).call(); //res=12
```

So, the `eval` and `Function` have the different return semantics.

And I can't just replace `eval` with the `Function()` in the legacy code. I will also be forced to change the calling side to add the `return`  in the code, passed to `Function()`.

Is there a way to avoid adding explicit return, so it will be possible to replace `eval` with the `Function()` in a transparent way (let's assume that we are not interested in the access to the local scope)?

Or maybe another technique exists, which can provide the equivalent of the `eval` which will minimise the risks of the global scope pollution and will provide the same return semantics as the original `eval`?

Comment: Ouch: old, likely insecure JS runtime, no support for 9-year old ES6, using eval. Heart attack for your security reviewers ;-)

Comment: Note that the result of ``eval(`var x = 5; var y = x*2;  y+2;`)`` is _not_ just "12", it's _also_ two new variables that now exist in global scope. `eval` is literally "run this code as if it was simply written here" (think of it as a latex macro: that code gets subbed in, then run). `new Function` has the benefit of doing literally that: creating a new function, with everything inside of it scoped _to_ that function.

Comment: @jarmod, yes! Let's say "Many thanks!" to the Adobe :), it's their products.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes, exactly this side effect with two "additional" global variables I'm trying to mitigate.

Comment: Except the important thing is that it's _not_ a side effect =) `eval` is a macro, so if you need scoped vars, just... write code that scopes your vars, for example by using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE): ``eval(`(function() { var x = 5; var y=7; y+=x; return y; })()`)``. Now the result _is_ 12, and only 12.

Comment: Also, if you're using Adobe scripting (presumably Photoshop and friend's jsx scripting?), then that's not just JS, it's ActionScript 3, which is based on JavaScript 1.5 (back when JS still had version numbers =D)

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do though? Because I've written a fair bit of Adobe AS3 and never needed eval: just write the functions you need in a dead flavour of JS and call that with whatever values you already have either from the Adobe APIs, or user input. (i.e. the toy problem you sketched here obviously doesn't need eval at all, just write a `function(x,y) { ...; return ...; }` and then call it =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Globally, we have the product (normal desktop app) that wants to pull some data from the Adobe products (from the documents, opened in these products). Since the Apple events are too slow, we implemented the custom interop that in two words just sends the generated jsx to the in-process (within the Adobe product process) jsx engine via socket. This is 2000+ times faster, but forces us to do some tricks like this one with `eval`. And the current goal is to minimise the risks of inadvertently corrupting the state of the JSX engine by the non-isolated `eval`.

Comment: Makes sense. Just note that you just provided a heap more details [that should really be in your post instead of a comment](/help/how-to-ask), And remember to not say "the JS engine is quite old", but just say what exactly you're using, and why, because that makes it _much_ clearer for current and future readers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for technical correctness, the initial `eval` block you're showing does *not* just result in 12, it results in *everything you wrote* =)

`eval` is a macro that halts JS execution, subs in the code you give it, executes it, and then resumes regular execution. So in this case the result is two new variables `x` and `y` in the same scope that `eval` was run in, and the "12" simply comes from the fact that assignments are returning operations.

If you don't want to introduce anything new to your scope, then remember that `eval` is a macro: make it sub in the code you need:

```js
eval("(function() { var x=5; y=7; return x + y; })()");
```

(Or use Alexander's solution where you create a "real" function with the `eval` as its function body)

And of course, that can take arguments just fine, too:

```js
var someVar = 5;
var someOtherVar = 7;
var result = 0;
eval(
  "result = (function(a,b) { return a+b; })(" + someVar + "," + someOtherVar + ")"
);
```

This will now run an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that does whatever it needs to do, returns 12, and then gets garbage collected.

But of course, and this is the important part: if that's what you need, then you don't need to eval anything. You can just write the function and call it with the values you already have. You almost never actually need `eval`, even in Adobe scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Just return evaled code from Function:

```js
const code = "var p = 2; p*2";
const fn = new Function('', "return eval('" + code +"')");

console.log(fn());
```

Or as Mike suggested:

```js
const code = "var p = 2; p*2";
const fn = function(){ return eval(code); };

console.log(fn());
```

Comment: Or just eval an IIFE instead.

Comment: Also note that this question appears to be about Adobe scripting, in which case we don't get any modern niceties like template strings, arrow functions, etc. etc. It's still stuck on JavaScript 1.5 (it's the absolute worst to write code for. You don't even get array.forEach - enjoy shimming _everything_...)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans forgot about es6, changed to `function`

Comment: Also as caveat, just in case: if the code loaded contains quotes, then the first option will run into all kinds of fun edge cases (you can't just blanket-escape `'` with a string replacement, for example), so you generally "have" to use an IIFE if you want things to only live for as long as you need them, or a regular function if you think you might need to call it more than once.